# How to get rid of margin property in media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I've been trying to get rid of the top & right margin from this title. I have tried margin:0 & margin: none 
and it hasn't worked. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```css
 p.title {
  font-family: 'Germania One';
  font-style: normal;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 150px;
  Position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  z-index:1000;
  text-align:left;
  margin-top: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left:200px;
}

@media (min-width:320px) and (max-width:425px) {

p .title{ 
  position:none; margin: 0 ; 
}
```

Comment: Typo on second style: p SPACE .title - Also: Please add a JSFiddle (with HTML)

Answer (score 2):

The selector in your media query cannot override the selector preceding the media query because they are not the same. Change the selector inside your media query from `p .title` to `p.title` and it will work.

---

The  (`space combinator`) in a `CSS selector` means the second part of the selector is a descendant of the first part, while chaining selectors without space it means the selector applies to the same element.

Therefore `p.title` selects any `<p>` tag with the class `title`, while `p .title` selects any element with the class `title` that is a descendant of a `<p>` element.

Here's the list of [CSS combinators](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp).

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I overlooked this

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `p .title` (with a space) instead of `p.title` inside the media query.

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo:

```
@media (min-width:320px) and (max-width:425px) {

    p.title{ /* No Space */
      position:none; margin: 0 ; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//Remove the space from p .title{} and put the media query like that-

@media (min-width:320px) and (max-width:425px) {

```
p.title{ 
  position:none; 
margin-top: 0; 
margin-right: 0; 
}
```

}

Comment: see [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)